# How do I use tor network to access my email account

Tags: security, help, onion-routing, email

Is there anyway to use tor network to securely access me email accounts like with onion?

I use tor browser to access my email account and sent my self an email to another email service and it showed my real IP address as the sender's IP address in the email sender's advance details.
It also showed I was using tor browser.

I have a startmail account, but I cannot not sign in using tor browser. I asked their support why, they said its security conflicts between the two.

I would like to use email over a secured network like tor or onion is this possible?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions:

1) If you like to use services such as gmail or yahoo which they have limitations for using TOR, you can set a VPN after TOR, which makes VPN's IP as your public IP, but you yourself connect to VPN through TOR.
You can check more at:[VPN Through TOR](https://mstajbakhsh.ir/socks-rocks-again/)

2) If you want to create your own hidden mail service over TOR, which only you (and whom you've told about it) can access it, you may check my site for finding about the steps. I have used a simple but powerful email server named [hMailServer](https://www.hmailserver.com/).

The steps are in [this link](https://mstajbakhsh.ir/configuring-a-hidden-email-server/).

[image: Configuring Hidden Mail Server]

Information about how to access to the mail server using PC, can be found [HERE](https://mstajbakhsh.ir/connecting-to-hidden-mail-server/). And if you prefer to access the hidden mail server using Android, refer [HERE](https://mstajbakhsh.ir/my-contribution-in-k9-android-mail-client/).

Answer (score 0):

There are mail services that actually provide an onion address like e.g. Protonmail:

https://protonmail.com/tor

https://protonirockerxow.onion/

If you are worried that your IP gets leaked somehow, you should use [Whonix](https://www.whonix.org/). When doing so, all traffic from your machine (not only Tor Browser) is sent over Tor.

Comment: Additionally, Tails can be used as well as Whonix.

Comment: https://protonirockerxow.onion/ the page loads but proton will not load after 10 minutes of it saying loading, it gives a message that says, the server is not responding. Please, try later.  I have been trying this for almost 24 hours.

Comment: that is weird. it actually does take for several minutes until the keys are generated (or whatever they are doing). do you have javascript enabled (middle position of security slider)? they need javascript in order to work correctly.

Comment: Yes the security slider is in the middle. I tried again and it still won't load.

Comment: strange. i just tried and it took me only a few seconds to get to the sign up screen.

Comment: I made a protonmail account and also got their protonVPN. they say i can use their VPN with Tor with no privacy leaks. Open tor first let it connect, then start the VPN. This way the VPN connects after Tor, not before.